# Jenkins jobs and GIT/maven

Tags: git, maven, jenkins

I want to execute a new task in jenkins.

I want to clone a git repository in jenkins workspace. This repository has two folders, one for each maven project.

But, I only have to execute mvn command in one of these folders.

How do I do to navegate to correct folder and ejecute a mvn command in jenkins?

I have checked "Consult repository (SCM)" option and I try to execute a shell script previously to run mvn command like that:

```
cd $WORKSPACE/CompositeApplicationExampleProject/
```

But I get this error:

```
[pruebaJenkins] $ /bin/sh -xe /clinker/jenkins/temp/hudson5899551334803596574.sh 
+ cd /clinker/jenkins/data/workspace/pruebaJenkins/CompositeApplicationExampleProject/
/clinker/jenkins/temp/hudson5899551334803596574.sh: 2: cd: can't cd to/clinker/jenkins/data/workspace/pruebaJenkins/CompositeApplicationExampleProject/
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failureFinished: 
FAILURE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally - having this kind of setup (multiple maven project in one git repository) is bad practice - especially when using jenkins. I need to deal with a big project that sadly uses this pattern and the experience is not one I would like to repeat.

Solution for your problem: Just add 2 maven jobs (install the plugin if not already done) and add the pom path under the build section of the respective job configuration. Example:

```
project_folder_1/pom.xml
```

If you want to build only when changes occur in the respective directory this is tricky and needs some tweaks in the git configuration of the job. You can use the additional behaviour "Polling ignores commits in certain paths". But be aware that this does not work all the time due to bugs in the git plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change directory at all.

Maven have a parameter `file` (or `f` for short) to specify custom pom.xml, for example:

```
mvn -file dir1/dir2/pom.xml package
```